# Weird Gecko behaviour (trying to pass an array of nsiDomWindows between js modules)

Tags: javascript, debugging, firefox-addon, xpcom, gecko

I'm writing a bootstrap firefox extension. Using firefox developer edition v36.2a

I have two problems that seem related, which I don't understand. The first one, mere annoyance:

my bootstrap Console.utils.imports a js file which loads my application (creates a namespace object and imports all other js files as properties on the namespace. All other files include this same namespace file and thus have access to each other. They even store state and everything works much similar to how node caches modules, eg it seems there is only one object of every class which is shared throughout the whole application. Now, this happens:

my namespace file does:

```
namespace.console  = Components.utils.import( 'you know the one/console.jsm' )
namespace.Services = Components.utils.import( 'you know the one/Services.jsm')
namespace.Cu       = Components.utils
```

Now in another file that imports this file, I get the namespace object, but `namespace.Cu` will be undefined. `console.log( namespace )` is fine however and shows me Cu, that I can expand and see all its properties and so on... All other things (console, Services, my own classes) are fine, but trying Cc, Ci etc from Components -> undefined.

In another place in my app I have a function (in file A) which returns an array of nsiDomWindows. A function in file B calls it and when it arrives, similar story: in console all looks fine, Array with ChromeWidows that I can look at. But it's no longer an array actually and is of type object and array[ 0 ] is undefined. If I put both classes in the same file they're fine.

For further confusion, I think I have already used this method in another file and all was fine:

```
// A.js
//
function A()
{
    b = new B()
    c = new C()

    let windows = b.windowList () // works fine, yields an actual valid array
                                  // with valid windows inside
    c.doSomething()               // broken, see below 
    c.doSomething( windows )      // passing it as a parameter 
                                  // doesn't help, still broken
}

// B.js
//
function B()
{
    this.windowList = function windowList()
    {
        let result = []

        // get open windows from nsiWindowMediator
        // foreach...
        // 
        result.push( nsiDomWindow )

        console.log( typeof result ) // Array -> it's completely valid here

        return result
    }
}


// C.js
//
function C()
{
    this.b = new B()


    this.doSomething = function doSomething( windows )
    {
        if( ! windows )

            windows = this.b.windowList()


        console.log( windows ) // in the console shows:
                               // Array[ ChromeWindow -> about:home ]
                               // I can inspect all it's properties, looks ok

        console.log( typeof windows )           // object
        console.log( windows.constructor.name ) // undefined

        console.log( windows[ 0 ]   )           // undefined

        // looping over the object properties shows that it does
        // have 1 property called '0' which points at undefined
        // note: there was only one open window in the array.
    }
}

// Note: the order in which I use Components.utils.import on these is B, C, A
```

I also wondered if this had to do with security measures in gecko, but no wrapper objects are to be seen anywhere, and afaik they should only shield content code from chrome code (this is all chrome code).

It's the kind of bugs that frustrates me, because I can't think of one sensible reason why the return value of a function shouldn't be the same thing on two sides of the call.

Lucky enough there is a workaround, I will have my make file concatenate all my js files and be done with Components.utils once and for all. Seems the less of the mozilla API I have to use, the happier and more productive I'll be.

I'm seeing errors from mozilla code as well. I just had an error saying "shouldLog is not a function" in Console.jsm. This function is clearly defined higher up in that file. The line that throws the error is an anonymous function that is being returned. That should inherit the scope without a doubt, but it doesn't. It might be that something is mangling return values and that this is related.

I filed a [bug on bugzilla](https://bugzilla.mozilla.org/show_bug.cgi?id=1116443) with a sample addon attached which demonstrates the first of the problems mentioned above.

**update**:

I'm sorry, I confused two things. I just figured out what happened in the first case of Cu not being available. I just loaded the file in which the problem happens before adding Cu to my namespace and since I did const { console, Services, Cu } = namespace on the global scope, this actually got evaluated before the property was made. The confusing part about it is that the console keeps references, not copies of the objects it shows you (an unfortunate design choice if you ask me) logging the namespace before the code in question gives you a view on it's state later on, which I missed to take into consideration.

That still doesn't explain how one function can return a perfectly sound value to a receiving function who receives something else, or how a function declared in Console.jsm doesn't seem to exist anymore in a function who inherits it's scope.

All in all, the first problem hasn't got anything to do with the others. I can't however create a reproducible small addon to illustrate the other 2. If I think of a way I'll upload it.

Btw: The pitfall by console can be easily seen (put the following in a javascript scratchpad):

```
let a = { some: "value" }

console.log( a )

delete a.some

// output: Object { }
```

For debugging purposes (usually it's main purpose) console has it's limits, and it usually better to set a breakpoint in a debugger or use `JSON.stringify`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I think I've narrowed all the fore mentioned problems to unloading uncorrectly. I had eventlisteners that I didn't remove and when they fired, objects or scopes can be invalidated.

Using the Extension Auto-Installer somewhat made these problems more severe because when reloading the addon when it hasn't properly unloaded creates an unreliable state of the addon code.

The shouldLog is not a function was because I thought that I had to unload all modules that I loaded with Components.utils.unload, so I unloaded Console.jsm.

After fixing that plus wrapping all the entry points into my software in try-catch blocks, things now run smoother. I now rarely have to uninstall the addon and restart firefox after updating the code.

There's nothing like a few fun days of debugging...

Answer (score 0):

I didnt read it all but:
I think the first issue is you are importing it wrong.

If you want to bring it to a certain namespace to the exported var from Cu.import you should do it like this:

Cu.import('resource://gre/modules/ctypes.jsm', namespace);

No need for the var blah = Cu.import

Console.jsm and Services.jsm export a var named te same thing.

You can even just do Cu.import('rsource://gre/modules/ctypes.jsm') and start using it like ctypes.blah

Also to get access to Cu do this:

```
var {Cu: utils, Cr: results} = Components
```

Next i think if you change the module in one scope, it will not change in other scopes until you do Cu.import again in that scope.

Comment: Thanks for looking into it. I know there is different ways to import, they all work, that's not the issue. The reason I don't pass my namespace to import is that console for example exports also ConsoleAPI which I don't necessarily want. I figured the first problem out however and it's not the same problem as the rest. I described that in the update.